# regex to ignore certain pattern

Tags: java, regex

```
String link[] = text.split("\\b");
```

I am using this code to split my line of text. The problem here is if my sentence contains "-" for example mithun-debnath then also it is separating the sentence. My objective is to split the sentence with all possible delimiters except "-".i.e. if the sentence "yes,i love my country very-much" then my array should contain link[0]=yes link[1]=i link[2]=love link[3]=my link[4]=country link[5]=very-much.I have not able to come out with an way  to ignore "-" in ("\b").

Comment: seems like java for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String link[] = text.split("(?!-)(?<!-)\\b");
```

Add a `lookahead` for the same.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mG8kZ9/2

Comment: the code that you have written,is it for "_" lookahead?

Comment: Probably "_" needs to be "\-"

Comment: @MithunDebnath you wanted to ignoe `_` out of `\b`.It is for that.check edit